# When Ext.Net App.direct is defined?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, ext.net

I have a problem using Ext.Net 2.5 and App.Direct:

```
 Ext.onReady(function() {
        App.direct.GetAll({
        success: function (result) {
            currentMessageId = result;
        }
       });
    });
```

The problem exist in body onload too.
When I Call the direct method in Ext.onReady it gives me this error: "Cannot Call GetAll of undefined."

But, when I call it instead a click button handler it works without problem.

So, the question is:

**When App.direct is defined?**

Answer (score 0):

In the Page Sources you could see the following.

```
Ext.onReady(function () {
    Ext.ns("App.direct");
    Ext.apply(App.direct, {
        TestDirectMethod: function (config) {
            return Ext.net.DirectMethod.request("TestDirectMethod", Ext.applyIf(config || {}, {}));
        }
    });
});
```

It is how a DirectMethod is rendered to a browser.

As you can see it is inside an Ext.onReady function. So, your onReady function is executed before that.

You can force rendering of our onReady function before your one using a ResourcePlaceHolder.

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" %>

<%@ Register Assembly="Ext.Net" Namespace="Ext.Net" TagPrefix="ext" %>

<script runat="server">
    [DirectMethod]
    public void TestDirectMethod()
    {
        X.Msg.Alert("DirectMethod", "Hello from Server!").Show();
    }
</script>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head runat="server">
    <title>Ext.NET v2 Example</title>

    <ext:ResourcePlaceHolder runat="server" Mode="Script" />

    <script>
        Ext.onReady(function() {
            App.direct.TestDirectMethod();
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form runat="server">
        <ext:ResourceManager runat="server" />
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

[Here](http://forums.ext.net/showthread.php?27271&p=121468&viewfull=1#post121468) is a description of possible options for a ResourcePlaceHolder's Mode.